# AppleScript to create spacing format like "S P A C I N G"?

Tags: applescript, automator, text

In order to format text documents in a more readable way it would be nice to format selected texts by an apple script executed via the context menu services in the following way:

1. select "text" with cursor
2. select context menu/services Spacing (to be created)
3. selected text is going to be formated to "T E X T"

Does anybody has the knowhow to program such a script?

Comment: You can also just increase the letter spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## AppleScript to Expand Text

The following AppleScript snippet adds a space between each character of a string. Copy and paste this code in **Applications > Utilities > Script Editor** to try it out:

```
set myText to "hello world"
set myResult to ""

repeat with c in every character in myText
    set myResult to myResult & " " & c
end repeat

display dialog myResult
```

## Automator Service

Using this script, you can use **Applications > Automator** to create your context menu service.

[image: Automator workflow to expand selected text]

[image: New text expand service in TextEdit]

1. Launch Automator.app
2. Create a new workflow, select **Service**
3. Add a **Run AppleScript** action
4. Copy and paste in the script:

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}

       set myText to input as string
       set myResult to ""

       repeat with c in every character in myText
           set myResult to ((myResult & " " & c) as string)
       end repeat

       -- Convert to upper case using `tr`
       set myResult to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (myResult) & " | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"

       return myResult
   end run
   ```
5. Select **Output replaces selected text**
6. Save and test your new service

Comment: Did you test this? I'm asking because this doesn't work for me in TextEdit  under OS X 10.8.5 and TextEdit under OSX 10.10.4. Or with or TextWrangler under OS X 10.8.5 the service doesn't show at all.  It's not a big deal for me as I have no reason to double-space text however what you've presented doesn't work on my systems.

Comment: Thank you very much of your quick and fitting answer!
I tried it, but the problem is, that the selected text isn't taken. If I set the myText to "asdkfsafg" it works perfect. If I use it with set myText to input I got error messages or the selected text gets deleted.
The input parameter in Automator is Text and every program.
What's going wrong?

Comment: @user3439894, it seems to be that we have the same behavior

Comment: @user139574 I tested the AppleScript on OS X 10.10.4 but not the service. What error message do you see? Have you tried creating other services using Automator? What happens if the service returns a static string such as `return "test"` instead of `return myResult`?

Comment: The error message from text edit is (translated from german): the service ... is not working, because the service ... isn't providing valid data.

returning of a static string is working

Comment: If a let the script output the input string just at the beginning it's correct.
So it seam to be, that an incorrect data format is caused by "repeat with c in every character in myText
        set myResult to myResult & " " & c
    end repeat" make this sense

Comment: I have updated the script; change the line `set myText to input as string`. The `as string` appears to be required. I have also typecast the `myResult` concatenation to ensure it remains a string type. This now works on OS X 10.10.4 as a service.

Comment: Yes,   i t ' s   w o r k i n g  ;-)
One final question: What's the command to switch all letters to upper case?

Comment: @Graham Miln, It's Working now for me in three differen't apps I'd use it in if I had a need.  While I don't have a need for this particular scenario nonetheless I've taken something useful away with me, so +1 here.

Comment: @user139574 converting strings to uppercase with AppleScript is discussed here: http://www.mindingthegaps.com/blog/2011/05/26/applescript-converting-uppercase-lowercase-applescrunix-style/

Answer (score 1):

To have the selected text converted to upper case, along with having a space added between each character, add the following line to the script posted by Graham Miln.

```
set myResult to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (myResult) & " | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"
```

So in **Automator** it would be:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set myText to input as string
    set myResult to ""

    repeat with c in every character in myText
        set myResult to ((myResult & " " & c) as string)
    end repeat

    set myResult to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (myResult) & " | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"

    return myResult

end run
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I have incorporated your `tr` line into the script.

Comment: @Graham Miln, No problem. I would have edited your answer directly however because it can be done in a number of ways I decided to post it as a separate answer since you only addressed the OP's upper case portion of his query as a link in a comment to your answer.